# real time signal ecg processing

Tags: matlab, real-time

I'm trying to detect r peaks of an ecg signal in real time. I'm supposed to work on it sample by sample. So I used a `for` loop that goes over the samples of the ecg signal I've already loaded. But it didn't work this way because the filter I'm using to filter the samples is a `window` filter, and another filter is `filtfilt` that needs data larger than 6 samples to operate.

I tried the following code:

```
for i=1:length(ecg)
```

But it doesn't work. is it okay to go with following instead:

```
for i=1:length(ecg(1:i))
```

will it still be real time processing this way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write

```
for i=1:length(ecg(1:i))
```

because `i` in `ecg(1:i)` is not declared yet.

Your question is not totally clear, but if you want to get the samples of an array until the *i-th* position for each index *i*, you can do as follows:

```
for i=1:length(ecg)
    pastSamples = ecg(1:i);
    ...
end
```

In this way, for each loop, you will work with all the samples until the *i-th* index.